# Was the asp.net GridView ever capable of using ViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, viewstate

I'm working on an old site that originated as a Visual Studio Website project, and which I'm converting to a Web Application in addition to other work. One page on the site uses a GridView, and sets the DataSource in code-behind using a DataTable. The GridView exposes a couple of BoundFields, as well as one TemplateField that has a checkbox in it. The GridView is configured to use EnableViewState.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Results" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" EnableViewState="true">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProcessDate" HeaderText="Process Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Classification" HeaderText="Classification" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notify?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="EnableSubmit(this);" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="EnableSubmit(this);" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The page also has a Submit button, and in the _Click handler, the code attempts to grab `Results.Rows`, and then digs around in order to determine which rows have their checkboxes checked. It does its subsequent processing based on the checked rows.

- The old site code does IsPostBack checking, and only calls DataBind when it's false.
- The page doesn't define either EnableViewState or ViewStateMode, which means they're both defaulting to true, according to MSDN.
- There's no call to DataBind in a master page or anything.
- The old site code does not do any manual persisting to the ViewState dictionary.
- Amazingly, the production version of this site actually works.

Since I've been working on this, I've found only threads and articles discussing how GridView doesn't actually use ViewState, and how in order to use data sent to the user, the DataTable used as the DataSource must be manually inserted into ViewState in the code behind, etc.

The version of the site I'm working on has been converted to a Web Application project, and it's targeting .NET 4.5. When I debug the site and break in `Page_Load` or `Submit_Click`, the `Results` GridView has a null DataSource and the Rows property has 0 count. This seems to agree with the current conventional wisdom concerning how GridView "works."

I'm well aware that for what this site is doing, this is a heinous implementation, and there are much better ways to do it. However, what I'm most concerned about is that I can't find any explanation as to how the old version is working.

Did GridView change at some point in its history to ignore its EnableViewState property? What does EnableViewState on GridView actually do? Could it be a difference between Website and Web Application projects?

How can this possibly be working?

UPDATE: Based on Bert Evans' example page, I tried out this modified page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    public class Thing
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    IEnumerable<Thing> Things
    {
        get
        {
            var things = new List<Thing>();
            things.Add(new Thing { ID = 1, Name = "One" });
            things.Add(new Thing { ID = 2, Name = "Two" });
            things.Add(new Thing { ID = 3, Name = "Three" });
            things.Add(new Thing { ID = 4, Name = "Four" });
            things.Add(new Thing { ID = 5, Name = "Five" });
            return things;
        }
    }

    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ThingGridView.DataSource = Things;
            ThingGridView.DataBind();
        }

        pageLoadLabel.Text = string.Format("On page Load, row count: '{0}'", ThingGridView.Rows.Count);
    }

    void OnClickMe(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onClickLabel.Text = string.Format("On click, row count: '{0}'", ThingGridView.Rows.Count);
    }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ThingGridView">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ThingButton" Text="Click Me!" OnClick="OnClickMe" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="onClickLabel" Text="[set on click]" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="pageLoadLabel" Text="[set on page load]" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The only differences are the labels that print out the row count in the page body. When executing this page. the first Page_Load call prints row count 5 to the page; however, in postback, the row count is 0 in both page load and the OnClick method.

Comment: Just look at the the view state in the HTML markup of the page.  Flip the enable viewstate on and off and look at the difference.

Comment: Are you saying it works in the production version, but not in yours?

Comment: @BertEvans Yes--somehow the old version is managing to pull data from the Rows property of the GridView during postback processing, and all that I've changed, aside from carving out some SQL access into a data layer, is upgrading the project to a Web Application (and possibly using a newer .NET version).

Comment: @bwerks You should be able to get Rows from the GridView. This is a barebones example; Rows is 5 every time. Is something else at play? I tested with .net 4.6.1 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0fe30395891bb3f19bc0ed8e92ea6e83

Comment: @BertEvans Thanks! I'll play around and see if I can figure out what the difference is. It doesn't matter that your codebehind is an embedded script and not a separate C# file, does it? The only things that jump out aside from that are that my case uses a DataTable as the underlying DataSource, and uses TemplateFields in addition to BoundFields in the GridView, but those things don't seem significant. Also, interestingly, your example doesn't call out EnableViewState...and yet it works! How strange.

Comment: @bwerks Essentially the runat server embedded script is just a shortcut (and less performant) way of writing your code behind. It doesn't matter functionally.

Comment: @BertEvans I tried out your example and edited the post to reflect my results. I modified it slightly to add some labels, and On postback, I still see 0 rows--could this be an IIS configuration problem? Maybe project settings? Something related to sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bert Evans and his example page I eventually isolated the problem. The bug is actually in the remarkably poor MSDN code example for UnityHttpModule, which integrates Unity DI with ASP.NET. UnityHttpModule detailed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664534(v=pandp.50).aspx.

In addition to not actually even compiling as listed, the class wires up the DI code on the InitComplete event, which takes place before ViewState is loaded, as described in this article: [ASP.NET 4.0 GridView OnRowEditing events not firing when using Unity 2.0 http module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852396/asp-net-4-0-gridview-onrowediting-events-not-firing-when-using-unity-2-0-http-mod). In my case, moving the DI code to execute on PreLoad fixed my problem.

Finally, for completeness, and for anyone else having problems with the MSDN Unity DI HttpModule, a different SO thread also provides a working example: [ASP.NET Dependency Injection HTTP Module (MS Enterprise Library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632019/asp-net-dependency-injection-http-module-ms-enterprise-library).

Answer (score 1):

Databinding is the process of translating the specified datasource for a control into a control tree that is rendered to the page. For `GridView`s, essentially, setting the `DataSource` property and calling the `DataBind` method translates an `IEnumerable`, or an `IEnumerable` extracted from another source like a `DataSet` or `DataTable`, into an HTML table with controls containing the data.

Each of the controls rendered into the table cells maintains it's own `ViewState`, so that when the page is posted back to the server, the `GridView` rebuilds the control structure, and populates the controls with the data in the `ViewState` (or rather, the Page initiates the rebuilding of the control structure and the `GridView` just participates).

The `DataSource` is not saved to the `ViewState`, only the state of the rendered controls.

Disabling the `ViewState` on a `GridView` prevents it from saving certain elements of it's own state, which will prevent it from being able to do things like pagination and sorting. Furthermore, if you disable the `ViewState` on the `GridView`, and you perform a postback (trigger an event on the client side that submits the page back to the server), then the `GridView` will show nothing when the page is re-rendered, because `EnableViewState` is inherited and the child controls will be prevented from saving their own state. The only way to get a `GridView` with a disabled `ViewState` to show data again after a post back would be to either re bind the data (call `DataBind` again with a data source that has data) or to have manually enabled `ViewState` on the child controls contained inside the `GridView` with the disabled `ViewState`. You mentioned that the `DataBind` on the page you are working on is guarded with `!IsPostback`, so it is only binding on the initial load of the page.

I don't know of anything changing such that the `GridView` at one point in time saved the `DataSource`, I believe this is how it always worked.

Comment: Ultimately the problem ended up being Microsoft's UnityHttpModule code from MSDN, but I've upvoted your responses as a thank you for your help! I wouldn't have figured this out without it.

Comment: @bwerks I'm glad you figured it out. I had copied your modification of my sample page to my box and it worked as expected, so I was at a loss to how to help going forward. Nice find though!